# How do I interrupt a program run from CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to get into C programming, but the larger the project get, the more often I want to interrupt programs I run from CMD.
Usually when running for example Python from the CMD, I can interrupt the script using CTRL+C. This however does not work. I have seen people say you can use CTRL+BREAK/PAUSE, but my keyboard does not have those keys.

Is there any way I could interrupt C programs I run from CMD? Maybe using a custom keybind (to tell CMD CTRL+C is the same as CTRL+BREAK)?

Answer (score 9):

If the **CTRL + C** doesn't work for you, use the **CTRL + break**, you should find **break** somewhere around your **page up** and **pause** keys, depending on what type of keyboard you're using. But **CTRL + break** usually works or even **ESC**

Comment: I am using a Qompaq Presario CQ57 laptop, if that helps anything ^^

Comment: [google image search](https://images.google.com/?q=presario+cq57+keyboard) looks like Pause is **fn** + **right shift** on the cq57 keyboard. Add a ctrl to that and you might get the equivalent of ctrl + break

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> instead - or to have it send both - only in Command Prompt.

Here are AutoHotkey scripts for both:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>:

  ```
  #IfWinActive, Command Prompt
  ^c::^CtrlBreak
  ```
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

  ```
  #IfWinActive, Command Prompt
  ~^c::^CtrlBreak
  ```

The tilde (~) makes the key retain also its original function.
To use, simply install the program, put the script you want in a file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C should work as long as it is a command shell / window, i use CTRL+C to stop CMD processes and batch files, problem is sometimes it asks if you want to exit in a app specific way (eg: Batch = "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"),then when you type "y" it exits so because i would not recommend this if you are debugging your'e C file. however i believe there are programs to edit key binds and / or bind a certan key to somthing (eg numpad7 = windows+R) ill have a look into it and edit this later on.

EDIT:

ive found this wich may be useful: http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows i don't know if it will work but its the best one i could find. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> Ctrl + Fn + S

If your notebook doesn't have a Break key (Dell Latitude 3490 for example).