# CTRL+C isn't working as interrupt in command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

When I run a command and I wanna to stop it via CTRL+C in CMD or PowerShell nothing happens.

If these shells are run with Administrator group CTRL+C is working fine. Yes I have UAC enabled.

On cygwin's bash shell everything is working fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Not all commands can be cancelled or cancelled at any point in time. Please provide an example.

Comment: @DanielB `ping google.com`

Comment: Yeah It used to work on my 1703 to but stopped :( I have build number 15063.483 from stable branch

Comment: check this link [How do I interrupt a program run from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1237833/how-do-i-interrupt-a-program-run-from-cmd/1237838#1237838) it might answer your question.

Comment: I don't have break button :/   Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 800 YAFUD

Comment: _Break_ button == _Pause_ so try **Ctrl+Pause**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the command:

1. It can be shell with running `.exe` file, where `.exe` files are not obliged to stop when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.
2. It can be shell with running `.bat`/`.cmd` file where it depends on few things if the script can be stopped.