# How to change process termination shortcuts in a terminal on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, interrupts

On Windows to close a program, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not always work (eg: ping).

To close anything immediately, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> can be used.

The problem I have is that on my Dell laptop, there is no <kbd>BREAK</kbd> key, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> exists as a replacement, so to do the equivalent of a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in linux on Windows, I need to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

How can I update/reconfigure Windows so that a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGBREAK?

Sources:

- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000145271/break-key-no-longer-available-on-dell-xps-e-and-m-series-portables
- [How do I interrupt a program run from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1237833/how-do-i-interrupt-a-program-run-from-cmd/1237838#1237838)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals
- https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/keyboard-alternative-to-break.3759101/
- https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/break-key-alternative/td-p/3826467

Comment: Alt-F4 is by far the most common way to kill an application. Do you mean to kill or halt a process running from the CMD prompt?

Comment: Here's a post with a solution to remap keys. Perhaps you can remap `Ctrl+Z` or some other key with `Ctrl` which you don't use, and remap it to really press `Ctrl+Break` with those other keys you select: https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I do